# print a sequence in a file

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I would like to print in a column in a new file the following

```
1_number_density_per_atom_1.xvg
1_number_density_per_atom_2.xvg
1_number_density_per_atom_3.xvg
.
.
.
1_number_density_per_atom_653.xvg
```

so I imagine the idea will be to write something like

```
printf "%s\n" "1_number_density_per_atom_1.xvg" "1_number_density_per_atom_2.xvg" "1_number_density_per_atom_3.xvg" ... "1_number_density_per_atom_653.xvg" > test.dat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
printf "%s\n" 1_number_density_per_atom_{1..653}.xvg > test.dat
```

Comment: out of curiosity if I wanted the output to be instead of column to be in a line?

Comment: change the `printf` format part, replace the `\n` with a space. Or just `echo 1_number_density_per_atom_{1..653}.xvg` will do exactly that.

Comment: there is something that I always wanted to try, if you would like to paste results from file (there is only one column in each file) 1_number_density_per_atom_1.xvg then 1_number_density_per_atom_2.xvg then 1_number_density_per_atom_3.xvg ... 1_number_density_per_atom_653.xvg can I d something like paste -d '  '  1_number_density_per_atom_{1..653}.xvg > test

Answer (score 1):

Using *GNU* `seq`:

```
seq -f 1_number_density_per_atom_%g.xvg 653 > test.dat
```